# Suggestions on how to automate login to website and upload data to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP website with a MySQL backend that I wish to be able to automate the process of logging in to the website and upload data from a text file to a table in the MySQL database.

I already have a manual process to upload the data from a webpage that prompts for the text file but I need to find a way to automate this process.

I am not sure where to start, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest to learn python, and investigate the usage of the Requests module. From there you can easily just login, and use the session to preform the upload request. 

Or if you have access to the database with the username and password, you can connect to the database within your python application and perform the query from there.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have been meaning to learn more about Python in any case so this may be a reason to do so. I am more of a "perl" guy though but I will certainly check this out.

Comment: Any programming language capable of sending http requests and interpreting results can be used to automate file uploads. You have to make up your mind which one you want to use, otherwise it is pretty difficult to help you.